Wold decomposition
Consider an AR(p) process
$$
Y_t=\phi_1Y_{t-1}+\ldots+\phi_pY_{t-p}+u_t
$$
Under certain circumstances, the process admits an $MA(\infty)$ representation
$$
Y_t=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\psi_ku_{t-k}
$$
Why this equation is fulfilled?
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \psi_k = \frac{1}{1-\sum_{i=1}^{p}\phi_{i}}
$$
See also Sum of autocovariances for AR(p) model

Welcome to CV, Martin.  If you would provide some context for this and an explanation of your notation I'm sure it would be better received.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Write the processes in lag operator notation, i.e.,
$$
\phi(L)Y_t=\epsilon_t,
$$
where
$$
\phi(z)=1-\phi_1z-\ldots-\phi_pz^p
$$
and
$$
Y_t=\psi(L)\epsilon_t,
$$
where
$$
\psi(z)=\psi_0+\psi_1z+\psi_2z^2+\ldots
$$
Hence, inverting the polynomial $\phi(L)$ gives
$$
\psi(L)=1/\phi(L)
$$
Now, evaluate both sides at $z=1$.
